# Transition page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I use Jquery script [Barba](http://barbajs.org/) to make fluid and smooth transitions between my pages.

I have Jquery scripts in my website. The most of my js functions are in a file named `main.js`.

To make my plugins works with Barba.js I use the [Views methods](http://barbajs.org/views.html).

So I put all my jQuery functions in my `main.js` like this :

```
var Homepage = Barba.BaseView.extend({
  namespace: 'homepage',
  onEnter: function() {

      // Here's they are my jQuery functions.
  },
});

Homepage.init();

Barba.Pjax.start();
```

It works for these jQuery functions.

The problem is that I have some other jQuery functions in two other pages : `index.php`and `single.php`. I have no more choice to put them in these pages because these Jquery functions contain php code.

So I put the other jQuery functions in my `index.php` and `single.php` like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

      // Here's they are my html code.

<script type="text/javascript">

 var Homepage = Barba.BaseView.extend({
   namespace: 'homepage',
   onEnter: function() {

       // Here's they are my jQuery functions.
   },
 });

 Homepage.init();

</script>
```

It doesn't works for these jQuery functions which are in my `index.php` and `single.php`. I can't see them in my pages. Like they don't exist.

Why and how to fix it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  What specific code is failing and how specifically is it failing?